# Checking if customer is login not refreshing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Now I implement the code below

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as AuthContext;

class Customer extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;
    private $objectmanager;
    private $authContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        Session $session,
        AuthContext $authContext
    ) {
        $this->objectmanager = $objectmanager;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->customerSession = $session;
        $this->authContext = $authContext;

        parent::__construct($context);        
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->authContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

        return $isLoggedIn;   
    }
```

But when I refresh my page it still say that it's login eventhough I already logged out. Below is the code of my template

```
<?php
    $customerHelper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helpers\Customer');
?>

<ul class="menu_list">
<?php if ($customerHelper->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li>                        
        <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account'); ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Account')) ?></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Logout')) ?></a>
    </li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Login')) ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>             
</ul>
```

Update:
- When I logout the account still thinks that I'm still login. When checking the function response it says that I'm still logged in. I'm not sure how to fix this. Upon checking the session when I'm logged out there are no values of firstname for the mage_cache_storage. But when I'm loggedin its being populated. I think a Javascript is populating this value that's why the PHP script still thinks I'm logged in.. I'm not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different approach

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml#L2-L11

```
    <!-- ko if: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="logged-in"
            data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome back %1', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="not-logged-in"
            data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Please <a href='%1'>login</a>", $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'))) ?>"'>
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Is_logged_in comes from the plugin

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Customer/CustomerData/Customer.php#L43

Dont forget `data-bind="scope: 'customer'`

Comment: Glad this helped